# chmod - file does not exist

Tags: php

I got a file that's located in
/uploads/original/img_329020110508094322.jpg

When I do `<img src="/uploads/original/img_329020110508094322.jpg" />` 
It will display properly

I want to change the user rights to 0606, so I do `chmod($this->fileName, 0606);`

($this->fileName stores the path above) but all I get is file or directory does not exist.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chmod()` operates on your filesystem. You must point to the image file within your filesystem, not within your web server.

Comment: ah ok. So I need to get /var/www/app_folder/uploads/original/img_329020110508094322.jpg instead thanks

Answer (score 0):

cause your path is relative to your web root. add the location of your web root before the file name, and chmod should work.

what i'm trying to say is that chmod uses exact paths on your file system :)

Comment: Assuming none of the paths in the URL are aliases to elsewhere.

Comment: and by "your path" or "the file name" i mean the path that you have in $this->fileName

Comment: @igna that's right! often though there are simple rule sets to describe the correlation between a file's web location and its file system location. in the simplest of web server configurations, my rule is correct ^^ so beware @ndef! it is the rule that describes this correlation that you should be looking for. mine might work! it might not ;)